# Valid? "The river is flowing."

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

What is the meaning of the "the river is flowing?" Is this valid usage?

> Websters, #2: River: A large quantity of a flowing substance

The river is already a flow by definition. Can the river be "not flowing?"

Comment: By implication you would presumably say there's something wrong with [The river is flowing again](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22the+river+is+flowing+again%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). I don't think there is. I think the question is Not Constructive.

Comment: Google [dry river](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1133&bih=713&q=dry+river). In most of these pictures, the river is *not* flowing.

Comment: It's also possible for a river to be frozen solid.

Comment: The runner is running. The hot chili is hot! I saw cars in the car park.

Comment: engineer + question on the english forum = -1 ;-)

Comment: It would be unusual, but qualificational (eg locational) padding (the river is flowing across the plains in its lower course / swiftly at this point) makes it sound more natural. And 'The river is flowing [again]' is possibly a transferred usage form say 'the river has dried up' with 'river' = 'river-course'; 'usual location of the river'; whatever, it is perfectly normal. Nobody gets into debates like "If it dried up for 3 months, is it really the 'same river' as before?"

Comment: The river is not flowing well. It's really down to a trickle. Yesterday, the river was flowing at cubic feet per second yesterday.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We would identify something as a river because we ordinarily expect it to have the characteristics of a river, even if some of those characteristics are temporarily suspended. That is, a permanent or semi-permanent stream would be a river even if it has temporarily stopped streaming, as noted in the comments, by drying up, being dammed up, or being frozen solid.

On the other hand, something which only temporarily takes on the characteristics of a river could be called so, metaphorically, but only while it possesses those characteristics. If they cease, the metaphor is no longer applicable. If I spill a jar of molasses, I may report a river of molasses running down the table leg, but once the flow stops, we would lose the river (having gained a pool).

Consider one's vocation. Someone who introduces herself as a pilot or a writer does not cease to be when she is not engaged in the act of piloting or writing. On the other hand, if I am speaking with my friend about two women across the room, one dancing and the other standing still, I might refer to the first as the dancer to distinguish between them. If she stops dancing, then she is no longer a dancer, and I will have to identify her otherwise-- unless she hands me her business card with "dancer" given as her occupation.

Comment: A riverbed or an arroyo is the same thing as a river?

Comment: @tchrist No, but a feature we know as a riverbed remains a riverbed even if it gains a river, something we normally call an arroyo remains the arroyo when flooded, and while the Colorado River doesn't reach the ocean any more, you still need to cross "the river" to drive from Mexicali to Nogales. The fact that the Colorado River in Mexico now functions more like an arroyo than a river doesn't change the fact that it is popularly known as a river.

Comment: OK, good enough — just checkin’. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think Webster's #2 here is letting us know that a river isn't *only* a flowing stream of water (like the Thames, the Rhine, or the Rio Grande), but a similar stream of *any* flowing substance - even substances that might be metaphorical. Hence, we can have a river of *lava*, a river of *tears*, a river of *blood*, a river of *ants,* or even a river of *joy*. Not all of these flow by default.

Take, for example, a river of *people* (such as at the start of a large marathon). It's not hard to imagine a commentator saying, "There was a delay for awhile, but now that the ambulance is out of the way, the river [of runners] is flowing again."

I don't find *the river is flowing* to be any more redundant than, say, *the author is writing*, *the scholar is studying*, or *the breeze is blowing*.

Answer (score 0):

When I checked the online Miriam-Webster dictionary, it describes river as:

> A large natural flow of water that crosses an area of land and hoes into an ocean, a lake etc.

This description of river as a 'flow' is obviously in contrast to a lake or ocean that doesn't flow.

To say 'a river is flowing' can be used as a form of emphasis as in the 'rain that is raining' or 'the night that is dark'.